# exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows--Rewriting the code

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code:

```
WHILE (v_Count > 0) 
LOOP

Select  v_Columns || CHR(10) ||  CHR(9)  || ColumnName || ',' ,
    v_Values || CHR(10) ||  CHR(9)  ||
    CASE ISNUMERIC(Val) 
        WHEN 1 THEN Val 
        WHEN 0 THEN '''' || REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Val)), '''','''''') || '''' 
    END
    || ',' into v_Columns,v_Values
FROM 

(           
SELECT D.TableName, D.ColumnName, D.Val
FROM            
(         
    SELECT ID, TableName, ColumnName, Val  
    FROM tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw OO  
    JOIN tblTemplates_Fields F ON OO.OtherObjectsField = F.FieldName 
    WHERE TemplateType IN ('All', v_TemplateType) 
    AND OO.Val IS NOT NULL 
    AND  (TemplateVersion = p_TemplateVersion or (TemplateVersion is null 
and p_TemplateVersion <> 'V8')) 

    UNION 

    SELECT FieldID, TableName, ColumnName, Val 
    FROM tblTemplates_Fields_OtherDestinations OD 
    JOIN  
    ( 
        SELECT ID, Val 
        FROM tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw OO  
        JOIN tblTemplates_Fields F ON OO.OtherObjectsField = F.FieldName 
        WHERE TemplateType IN ('All', v_TemplateType) 
        AND OO.Val IS NOT NULL 
        AND    (TemplateVersion = p_TemplateVersion or (TemplateVersion is 
null and p_TemplateVersion <> 'V8')) 

    ) UsedIDs 
    ON OD.FieldID = UsedIDs.ID


) D


JOIN USER_TAB_COLS C  ON upper(D.TableName) = upper(C.TABLE_NAME) AND 
upper(D.ColumnName) = upper(C.COLUMN_NAME)
WHERE (v_UpdateComp = 0 OR D.TableName <> 'tblComp') 
AND (v_UpdateCompInd = 0 OR D.TableName <> 'tblCompInd') 
ORDER BY D.TableName, D.ColumnName
)

WHERE TableName = v_TableName ;

 v_Count := v_Count -1; 
end loop;
```

where v_count is a number and can range in values from 5 to 6.

The issue here is that because of the looping, more than one value is tried to be stored into v_Columns and v_Values and getting *exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows* error.
I am unable to figure out how to rewrite this piece of code so that it works fine.

How can i rewrite this code?

Comment: It's not the loop that causes the problem. You query returns more than 1 row.

Comment: This seems like a complicated way of rolling your own LISTAGG() capability.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the most suspicious thing is `UNION` which - if both `SELECT`s return at least a row - produce two rows. You can't fit two rows into those variables and got the error.

What to do? If possible, rewrite it to a cursor `FOR` loop which will return row-by-row.